# resort able items in listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

how can i turn my listbox to resort able by dragging and dropping in vb.net...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since user-defined sorting is not an inherent feature of a listbox, you would need to add controls and wire up the events to do this yourself.

Also make sure that the auto-sort property is not set.

Normally people expect a listbox to be sorted alphanumerically by the list contents.  That makes finding the value you want much easier.

If you want to show multiple data values to the user and allow them to sort by any of them, you're looking for a datagrid, not a listbox.  Grids support sorting, paging, etc.